# Insert query is not working access Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

My code is

```
Dim tmpSQL_2 = New StringBuilder
        tmpSQL_2.AppendLine("Insert into table(tbl_ID,tbl_Type,tbl_Type) ")
        tmpSQL_2.AppendLine(" VALUES ")
        tmpSQL_2.AppendLine("(@tbl_ID,@tbl_Type,@tbl_Type) ")
        Using tmpCMD As New OleDbCommand(tmpSQL_2.ToString, conn)
            tmpCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl_ID", "0")
            tmpCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl_Type", "my type")
            tmpCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl_Ser_Id", "my type")
            tmpCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
```

for inserting into table but it is not working.

I'm not getting any error also. what should be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it in defferent way ...

```
Dim cmdText As String = "INSERT INTO table(tbl_ID,tbl_Type,tbl_Type) VALUES (?,?,?)"
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New OleDBCommand(cmdText, conn)

With cmd.Parameters
    .Add("@p1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 0
    .Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "my type"
    .Add("@p3", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "my type"       
End With
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: @RahulShirphule .. I just changed those 3 lines .. it's updated

Comment: @RahulShirphule .. it's changed .. for accessDB